# Prevent Google Chrome From Removing Favorites Bar

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have my favorite websites saved in the favorite bar  in `Google CHROME` like below

[image]

However, once I click one, the bar disappears.

[image]

How do I get it to permanently stay in place, so I don't have to open a new tab each time I wish to click on one of my favorite links.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To make the bookmarks bar appear permanently,
right-click it and make sure “Show bookmarks bar” is checked. 
Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on the keyboard.

[image: Screenshot: bookmarks bar context menu]

Comment: @Seiyria irritatingly, that's the same hotkey to build a project in Visual Studio, this has caused me to lose my bookmarks bar from time to time.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Hotkeys can be changed :P